# How to handle object properties not garanteed to exist within template tags in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Getting fatal error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'propThatSometimesDoesNotExist')` with following code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <img v-if="obj.propThatSometimesDoesNotExist" :src="obj.propThatSometimesDoesNotExist">
  </div>
</template>
```

Using a computed property instead works fine, but that's not ideal in my particular case (the above is a simplified version of my project).

Can I somehow keep the syntax above while avoiding fatal errors? Perhaps something like [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) looking like `:src="obj?.propThatSometimesDoesNotExist"` (except of course this doesn't work)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following condition using && operator to ensure that the object is different than null :

```html
 <img v-if="obj && obj.propThatSometimesDoesNotExist" :src="obj.propThatSometimesDoesNotExist">
```

Knowing that the `v-if` has the high property when using it with other attributes and directives, so the value checking is done before adding to the `src`

Comment: Works and no problem with Jest!

Comment: Good, if you're using typescript you could use optional chaining

Answer (score 1):

You can use optional chaining on v-if:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      obj: null
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <img v-if="obj?.propThatSometimesDoesNotExist" :src="obj.propThatSometimesDoesNotExist" />
</div>
```

Comment: Works but can create problems with Jest.